# TINKER molecular modeling software package- Boltzmann constant units

Tags: computational-physics, units, physical-chemistry, software, molecular-dynamics

I use the [TINKER molecular modeling software package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinker_(software)) (version 7.1.2) for computational physical chemistry. There is an extra file (extra1.f) included for the user to edit and incorporate in their own unique forces/energies to the dynamics of the molecules. The energy I want to add contains the Boltzmann constant, but I am having trouble determining if it is correct to use the units of calorie (kcal/mol K) or joule (kJ/mol K). The source code seems to use both units in different ways. Is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Never seen it before but the user guide has units in it

Comment: That is true. The problem is that TINKER's has a parameter called boltzmann, which is listed as having units g ang/ps/K/mol (SI unit of Joule), but all other energies in the program are listed using kcal/mol (calorie). I'm not completely convinced which way is correct

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about compiling/debugging code and not physics.